# Java OO class design example of haircut in real life

Tags: java, class, oop

guys i'm very new to OOP. 
I want to design the OO classes to represent how the human perform actions of haircut

I have the intial classes blueprint like this:

```
class Human {
    Human(){}
    class Hair{
        private int length;
        Hair(){
            this.length=10;
        }
    }
}
class Tools{
    Tools(){}
    class Scissors{
        Scissors(){}
    }
}
class HoldingScissors{
    public void makeHairCut(Human theHuman){
        theHuman.Hair.length = 5;
    }
}
```

However, i don't know how to link up the relationships between them.
I want the human 'grab' the scissors first, and then have the ability to make a haircut.
Can someone please show me how to achieve this?

Comment: That's default constructor @ConcurrentHashMap

Comment: @ConcurrentHashMap, that is valid syntax.

Comment: How complex do you need to go ? this can be a rabbit hole, looks like you want real world function where you will need to implement hands and then a tool factory to get you the correct tool ... and so on

Comment: As per @KennethClark comments, you really need to define the scope of what you are doing.  In particular you need to define _what_ you are modeling.  I can gleen from your declarations that you are assuming a human's hair is of uniform length and a "haircut" involves cutting down that length (or perhaps adding to it?).  It helps to define these assumptions.

Comment: thanks guys, i want to modify the hair length and shorten it., @Keenth Clark, thanks for your advices, yes, i also want to implement the human hand, and the real world function

Comment: In true OO function, Human can hold scissors however not implement haircut , only stylist which extends human implements stylist which has allocated tool factory and has `doHairCut(customer)` method .. again this can be crazy complex.

Comment: @Kenneth Clark, thanks very much, your advices are very helpful, i think i will get some books to dig deeper into this topic

Comment: Scissors ideally cut hair, not humans. It could be something like `scissors.cut(hair)`.

Comment: hi@ChristofferHammarström, thanks very much, I think you provided a more simple solution for the class design

Comment: As per @KennethClark's remarks, OO is _not_ a requirement, it's a tool.  You should use it as it makes sense.  It _does not_ make sense to model every little detail (if so you will create spaghetti code that is incomprehensible and not useful).  You should decide what your model is and then create OO programming accordingly.  You can go the super anal route and model _everything_ but it's better to drop objects that do not do anything.  For instance, if all scissors do is cut hair and barbers can cut hair, then you are _not_ modeling scissors so there is no need for a scissors class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HoldingScissor should probably not be a class, but a property that enables the execution of a class of actions.

there are, however, one million ways to model this. there are two things about OO: message passing and encapsulation; do not focus on object granularity alone as you would be chasing the wrong abstraction

```
abstract class Action {
  public void perform();
}


public class CutHairsAction {

 Human agent,target;

 public  CutHairsAction(Human agent, Human target) {
   if (agent.getHolding() == null) throw new IllegalStateException("agent not holding scissors"); 
   if (! agent.getHolding() instanceOf Scissor) throw new IllegalStateException("agent not holding scissors"); 
 if (target.Hair.lenght < 5) throw new IllegalStateException("target hair short enough"); 

   this.target = target;
   this.agent = agent;
 }

 public void perform() {
 target.Hair.length = 5;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing some classes here in my opinion (not to mention these classes should be public--not internal as you have them written).  There should be a subclass of `Human` called `Barber` (or perhaps `Stylist`).  *Only* the barber should be allowed to make changes to the Human's haircut (and a particular human *could* take the roll of a "barber"--including the person getting a haircut--hey people cut their own hair *all* the time!).

I think it's overkill to define a scissors class unless you intend to model the action of scissors (which with your simple notions it is clear you *do not* intend to model what scissors actually do).  Instead, a barber (or stylist) should be able to directly modify a human's hair cut (which let's keep it real--is really the length of hair here).  In real life, a barber may use scissors (or shearers) but you are not modeling *that* part of this, so it's superfluous to create a scissors (or shearers) class.

If you were to legitimately have a `Scissors` (or Shearers) class, then you would need to differentiate how different Scissors (or shearers) cut hair.  If you have no such distinction, then having the class makes no sense.  For instance, dull scissors might cut hair differently than sharp scissors.  So if a barber used dull scissors (or a grade of "dull") it might cut differently for the same barber using different scissors--if they *all* cut the same, then you are *not* modeling scissors and thus there is no need for a `Scissors` class/object.

Comment: Thanks Jared, yes, i had considerd this kind of questions, but i think that in real world, any person should be able take the scissors and modify their hair length